# How to change React parent component size based on child component size without rendering child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**I've created a React component which takes any component and renders it as a Pop-up.** A parent component receives the component to be rendered (popped up). The rendered component is here the child component which using react-sizeme to get its size and pass back to parent component. **The parent component must take the dimensions of child component, so adjusts' its height and width**. This is the code:

```js
class Popup extends React.Component<IPopupProps,IComponent>{
    constructor(props:IPopupProps){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            childComponent:this.props.children,
            style:{
                height:0,
                width:0
            }
        }     
    }
    
    // This function runs two times, before and after rendering child component
    // & so have an improper visualization as the size is changed twice here
    
    public OnSize = (size:any) =>{
        const width = size.width +20;
        const height =size.height+20;
        this.setState({
            style:{height,
                width             }
        })
    }

    public render(){
        return(
            <div className='popup'>
                <div style={this.state.style} className='popup-content'>
                    <a className="close" onClick={this.props.onExit}>
                            &times;
                    </a>
                    <this.state.childComponent onSize={this.OnSize}/>                    
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

The initial width and height is set to 0. So it doesn't renders properly. So is there any way so that to hide the child component or avoid its rendering before parent component gets the size?

**EDIT: We can't get the size until the child component is rendered. So is there any trick to get this done. Just a component needs to be popped-up properly.**

**EDIT 2: Here's the PropsBuilder.tsx which calls the Popup.tsx and sends the component to display as children**

```js
class PopupBuilder extends React.Component<IPopupBuilderProps, IPopup>{
    constructor(props:IPopupBuilderProps){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            showPopup:false
        }
    }

    public togglePopup = () =>{
        this.setState({
            showPopup:!this.state.showPopup
        })
    }

    public render (){
        return(
            <React.Fragment>

                    <button onClick={this.togglePopup}>{this.props.trigger}</button>

                    <React.Fragment>
                        {this.state.showPopup?<Popup onExit={this.togglePopup} >{this.props.component}</Popup>:null}
                    </React.Fragment>

            </React.Fragment>
            
        )
    }
}

export default PopupBuilder;
```

Comment: shouldComponentupdate hook is there for such case

Comment: I was searching about this in the mean time. Actually we can't get the size of a component until it is rendered. We can't use shouldComponentUpdate I guess as it will be not rendered at all. So issue is now how to properly  display any component as a pop-up.

Comment: Just render it offscreen (i.e. outside the viewport) at first, get the measurements, then render it onscreen.

Comment: @JaredSmith
This suggestion worked actually. I combiled it with Shevchenko answer

Comment: @NikhilPatil it's similar to an old, old trick in game dev. Since you only have such a small frame budget for games (16 ms) you typically "draw" the next frame to an image buffer in memory (fast and cheap) and then swap the whole thing all at once for what's on screen instead of drawing every object in the scene incrementally (slow/expensive).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, this looks like more general DOM/JavaScript question.

Consider such case:

```
const span = document.createElement('span');
span.innerText = 'hello';
span.getBoundingClientRect() // -> { width: 0, height: 0, top: 0, … }
```

This is an indicator that you don't know the dimensions of the element until it is in DOM (Rendered in react);

```
document.body.appendChild(span);
span.getBoundingClientRect(); // -> {width: 50, height: 16,  …}
```

My recommendation to you in this case are:

1. Child component should accept a property (function) from Parent one
2. Use React "ref" feature to find actual dimensions of Child element
3. Call the function in 'componentDidMount' (use componentDidUpdate if child can change dynamically), passing it child component dimensions.

If you don't have access to child component. You may wrap it like this:

```
// Popup.tsx

class Popup .... {
 ...
   render() {
     <Measurer>{this.props.children}</Measurer>
   }
}
```

and implement the logic of fetching dimensions in it. Measurer is a direct child of Popup and their communication can be controlled by you.

Comment: There is a problem with this approach:

The Parent component (Popup.tsx) receives the childComponent from its main Parent component (PopupBuilder.tsx). So the child component to be rendered is not imported in the same class and so I'm unable to send any method to the child component

I even tried replacing the 'any' type of childComponent to 'React.ComponentClass' as well as 'React.Component'. But it didn't worked

Comment: This <Measure/> part worked. Thanks. Did some extra changes in the <Measure/> and my popup.tsx. And made the opacity set to 0 for the <Measure/>

Comment: Accepting it as the answer